# index files from a folder with subfolders and store location and filename

Tags: php

Hi I am looking for help to write a short script which will locate all files in a folder (which has sub-folders) list the path and filename in two seperate values before submitting to a database.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So basically i have an index of path and filename within a database which i can search later on...

Comment: This could help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#93547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

print_r(getPathFiles("./"));

function getPathFiles($dir) {
    $ite=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $foo=new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite);
    $ret=array();
    foreach ($foo as $path=>$cur) {
        $ret[]=array('dir'=>dirname($path),'file'=>basename($path));
    }
    return $ret;
}

?>
```

Comment: This looks cool, this basically returns an array of all files within a directory?

Comment: yes, it returns an array (with the keys: 'dir' and 'file') for each file found in any subdir of the given path in one big array

Comment: I am fine if i use this ../../../ but as soon as i use ../../../collections it brings back nothing...although the folder definitely exists...any ideas?

Comment: Its me being a knob, don't worry! :)

Answer (score 1):

i have a recursive function to delete a folder, you'd have to change it so instead of calling the ´unlink´ function you could save it in a variable or in a database..

```
public function deleteFolder($dirname) {
        if (is_dir($dirname)){
            $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
        }
        if (!isset($dir_handle) || !$dir_handle){
            return false;
        }
        while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file)){
                    //change this line
                    unlink($dirname."/".$file);
                } else {
                     //recursive call
                    $this->deleteFolder($dirname.'/'.$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir_handle);
        //also change this one
            rmdir($dirname);
        return true;
    }
```

hope this helps.. good luck!